# How to get parent element text and remove child element text selenium c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

i'm a newbie of automation testing, now i'm using selenium C#.
I have a problem, i want to get text from a element, but the code :

```
<div class="item">
Text1
<span>textdontwant</span>
</div>
```

and my statement

> driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='contactList']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]")).Text;

Get:

> Text1textdontwant

I need only parent element text is :

> Text1

Anyone have solution?
Thanks so much!
here HTML:

```
<div id="contactList" class="web z-data-list" tabindex="30" style="position: relative;">
   <div style="overflow: visible; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
      <div class="virtualized-scroll testing" style="height: 657px; width: 304px;">
         <div aria-label="grid" class="ReactVirtualized__Grid ReactVirtualized__List" role="grid" tabindex="-2" style="box-sizing: border-box; direction: ltr; height: 657px; position: absolute; width: 304px; will-change: auto; overflow: auto;">
            <div class="ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer" style="width: auto; height: 2198px; max-width: 304px; max-height: 2198px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
               <div style="height: 44px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100%;">
                  <div class="contact-list__add flx flx-al-c nav-button_add_friend clickable  "><i class="fa fa-icon-add-friend contact-list__add__icon "></i><span class="contact_add_friend_item" data-translate-inner="STR_CONTACT_ADD_FRIEND">Thêm bạn</span></div>
               </div>


             <div style="height: 72px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 266px; width: 100%;">
   <div class="item minimized rel list-friend-conctact  ">
      <div class="avatar avatar--m list-friend-conctact__avatar">
         <div class="avatar-img  outline" style="background-image: url(&quot;//s120.avatar.talk.zdn.vn/4/8/c/f/27/120/c5ee9f2b5a5a87d227fe2faf376f2e2c.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-friend-conctact friend_onlines_dot"></div>
      <div class="item-title list-friend-conctact__title has-status ">Text1
<span class="friend_online_status truncate" style="top: 0px; left: 3px;">Text dont want</span>
</div>
</div>


   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you add full HTML here ?

Comment: @Prany yes :v i updated

Comment: Where ? Can't see any update mate

Comment: @Prany just completed

Comment: Now on the basis of HTML can you edit which specific field/text you're looking for ?

Comment: @Prany i updated again :v tks for read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided to extract the text **Text1** you can use the following code block:

```
IWebElement myElem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='item-title list-friend-conctact__title has-status']"));
string myText = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", myElem);
```